# Slow FPS with OpenCV C++ RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, frame-rate

I have written a simple C++ program using OpenCV to test fps on raspberry pi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace cv::ml;

int main(void) 
{
    VideoCapture camera(0); 
    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);
    
    Mat frame;
    while (camera.read(frame)) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < frame.dataend - frame.datastart; i++)
            std::cout << frame.data[i];
    }
}
```

I then use the following scrips to test fps.
The first uses raspvid as the input, the second used my C++ program as input
The raspvid version gets to the 25fps.
My C++ program never goes over 10fps.
Any ide why this is?

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -t 120000 -o -| ffmpeg -re -i pipe:0 -y -an -c:v copy -f null /dev/null
```

and

```
./PiImageAnalyzer.out | ffmpeg -re -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 25 -i pipe:0 -y -an -c:v copy -f null /dev/null
```

Update

these scripts can also be used

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -t 120000 -o -| ffplay -i -
```

and

```
./PiImageAnalyzer.out | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 25 -i -
```

Comment: printing to terminal is slow. I think you are printing 921600 values per frame? Can you try to remove the cout part and the for-loop?

Comment: I tried that, replaced it with std::cout << frame; it made no difference.

Comment: I wouldnt output the frame via cout at all. Do you need that for your ffmpeg pipe? What's your plan in the end? Can you try `while (camera.read(frame)) {std::cout << "read a frame" << std::endl;} to test general capturing capability?

Comment: could the problem not be OpenCV needing to convert from H264 from the camera to its Mat format?

Comment: could be very well possible. If you measure the fps without artificial overhead like the cout, you could be certain ;)

Comment: try the opencv VideoCapture GStreamer pipe as used in the answer of: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244975

Comment: also have a look at different backends of VideoCapture: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html and try to find out which one is most efficient with a raspberry pi